# Integrating game with libGDX

Tags: libgdx

I have multiplatform 2d game made in kotlin, which has its own game-loop, fires evens which then can be used to construct GUI/modify it. The project is very modular and quite flexible.

The game loop has multiple implementations using coroutines, java threads, javascript requestAnimationFrame, setInterval, etc.
I have multiple implementations of GUI, including text interface and HTML/javascript.

Now I decide to give it a try and make GUI using libGDX. I am playing around with it a bit trying to integrate it with each other (first using "desktop" platform).

My game loop goes through all necessary components like "unit spawner", "unit container", "projectile container", etc. passing "delta" to all of these. These components are firing different events like "unit moved", "projectile fired", etc.

If I understand correctly, so far I see 2 options on how to integrate:

- Keep my gameloop, collect relevant events related to UI update and then update all of them in `render` function of my `ApplicationAdapter` (because I cannot render outside of `render` methods, right?).
- Use `Actor` class and for every component (or group of components) and use it's `render` and basically let libGDX handle gameloop for me.

How would you proceed? Are there any other options to go?
I want to keep my design flexible and modular, not to be tightly bound to libGDX, and rather make it another GUI implementation if possible.

Comment: So your game already has a rendering system and you want to render a LibGDX surface on top of it?

Comment: Not doesn't really, most of code is invisible "core". HTML gui is pretty much responding to events and creating HTML/CSS.

Comment: Oh, by GUI, you mean *all* rendering, not just the HUD and menus?

Comment: Yes, everything visible.

Comment: OK. I do not recommend Actor and Stage for the game, especially if you already have created the logic. Stage is mostly useful just for UI (menus and HUD). `render` is the function called repeatedly in the LibGDX game loop and is called on the OpenGL render thread. All drawing in LibGDX must be done on this same thread. You can call `Gdx.app.postRunnable` if you need to send an action to be run on the render thread. Or use the libktx ktx-async library if you like coroutines.

Comment: I built a game-jam game with Actor and Stage, and it was just cumbersome to try to adapt what I wanted to do to such a specific design. Even the author of that part of the library once said he tried to make a game with it and recommended just using it for UI.

Comment: `postRunnable` looks great! that way I will just need to implement listener of events, that will then forward these actions to necessary rendering.

Comment: If you use ktx(https://github.com/libktx/ktx) there's also a `Disptachers.KTX` you can use in coroutines to do stuff on the rendering thread.

Comment: Yes, I will check that too.